# How to displaying Emojis and UTF-8 text in Flutter/Java

Tags: java, angular, flutter, utf-8, emoji

I'm trying to simply show text in Flutter, but text should be in UTF-8 and should be able to display emojis also.

I can't get them both working at the same time, because when I try to decode for example input: löäjhlöäpüüõä', which is saved to base like so:
[savedEmojis with UTF8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2pGt.png)

- to UTF-8 in Flutter with emojis -
  `child: Text(utf8.decode(item.content.runes.toList()))`

I will get "FormatException: Invalid UTF-8".

If I do other way around, and input is not decoded, the emojis work fine, but UTF-8 chars are ruined.
[UTF8text without decode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlver.png)

-- Emojis are inserted to DB through Angular "ngx-emoji-mart"

Thank you in advance, if you know how to resolve this text problem

Comment: I can not say I know flutter but can you put a reproducer in github ? I just want to investigate and learn flutter :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java codes inside a string:
String string = 'This is an example with emoji \u2764';

Comment: This I believe would work until special characters are absent. For example: "äöä" would display correctly only emojis, but special chars are still ruined.